# Find the length of the loop of the given parameterized curve: $x=12t-4t^3$ and $y=12t^2$

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the loop of the given parameterized curve: $x=12t-4t^3$, $y=12t^2$
[image]

I'd like to get some views on different ways of solving this problem. Is there an easy way to know how to sketch this curve? Using a computer I saw what the graph looks like and that indeed there is a loop, so I could find the values of $t$ that parameterize that loop, but I'd like to be able to do this without computer aide.

Would eliminating the parameter be a good idea here? I couldn't find a nice way to do that.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: use table of values?

Comment: I see no such loop. Can you double check the source?

Comment: Hm... That is the problem word for word... Could webassign be wrong??? It's happened before..

Comment: No, there's a loop in the graph, but your question leads one to expect to see a picture.  Do you know Green's theorem?

Comment: Question is word for word from webassign,but I see what you mean. The equations don't parameterize a loop, but there is a loop in the graph

Comment: Sorry Green's theorem has nothing to do with this.  Somehow I assumed you wee asking for the area inside the loop; don't really know why.

Comment: I would not ignore the importance of computer aid for this problem. In the spirit of the answer of @DanielMcLaury, the computer picture gives you a hint that there are two parameter values $s \ne t$ which give the same values for the ordered pair $(x,y)$. Now your job is to find those values, which is what that answer does.

Comment: As for eliminating the parameter, $x^2$ has only even powers of $t$, so its terms are equivalent to powers of $y$: $x^2=12y-\frac{2}{3}y^2+\frac{1}{108}y^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a "loop," it means the curve self-intersects.  So we have $s$ and $t$, $s \neq t$, with
$$12 s - 4 s^3 = 12 t - 4t^3$$
$$12s^2 = 12t^2$$

Looking at the second equation, we have $s^2 = t^2$, i.e. $s = \pm t$.  If $s \neq t$, it follows that $s = -t$.  Plugging this in, we have

$$12(-t) - 4(-t)^3  =12t - 4t^3$$
$$-12 t + 4t^3 = 12 t - 4t^3$$
$$8 t^3 - 24 t = 0$$
$$8t(t^2 - 3) = 0$$

The solutions to this equation are $t = -\sqrt{3}$, $t = 0$, and $t = \sqrt{3}$.  Interpreting these in the context of the problem, it's no surprise that when $t = 0$ we get the same result as when $t = -0$, but now we know that there is also a loop between $t = - \sqrt{3}$ and $ = \sqrt{3}$.

Of course this analysis had some parts that are special to this particular curve.  In general, if the equations were more complicated we might not be able to get a straightforward solution like this, because (for instance) we might not be able to eliminate anything, and/or we might have to solve a very high-degree polynomial.  The general problem itself is just inherently difficult, and there is a whole area of math (computational algebraic geometry) devoted to its generalizations.  So your best hope for a problem like this is to look at the exact equations you are dealing with and hope that you can find a trick that works for them in particular.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the length of the loop in the curve. As the curve is symmetric wrt $y$-axis we can limit to the interval $[0,\sqrt 3]$
$$L=2\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2} \, dt$$
$$x'(t)=12-12 t^2,y'(t)=24 t$$
$$L=2\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{576 t^2+\left(12-12 t^2\right)^2} \, dt=\\=
2\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{144 \left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,dt =24\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \left(t^2+1\right)dt=24\left[ {\frac{{t^3 }}{3} + t} \right]_0^{\sqrt 3 }=48 \sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

As for eliminating the parameter, $x^2$ has only even powers of $t$, so its terms are equivalent to powers of $y$: $$x^2=12y-\frac{2}{3}y^2+\frac{1}{108}y^3$$

Perhaps (or perhaps not) at this point you would find it easier to sketch $$x=\sqrt{12y-\frac{2}{3}y^2+\frac{1}{108}y^3}$$ plotting $x$ as a function of $y$. And then plot its reflection as well.